# Horizontal Fields

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-formly

Looking at this example: http://angular-formly.com/#/example/bootstrap-specific/advanced-layout

What makes the fields display horizontally?  Is it the `row` class on the field group?  Or at the `col-xs-6` classes on the individual fields (when looking just at the First/Last name fields)?

I am asking because at my work we are unable to use the twitter bootstrap (arg!) and I am having trouble making fields get on the same lines like this example when not using the bootstrap.

Do you have to use the bootstrap classes in order to get fields on the same row?

Comment: it's the `col-xs-6`, see what properties they use and you can create your own rules

Comment: What do you mean by see what properties they use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CSS. They are wrapped in a div with the col-xs-6 class applied. That class is floated left and has a width of 50%.

```
.col-xs-6 {
   width:50%;
   float:left;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6njkou1g/

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the browser support you need, you might consider [this example](http://angular-formly.com/#/example/other/advanced-layout-flex) which doesn't require bootstrap at all and instead uses [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes) to do layout. Otherwise, what Brian said about implementing a subset of bootstrap's grid system yourself wouldn't be too tricky...

Answer (score 0):

Use `col-xs-6` for two columns.

```
  <form class="form">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1" placeholder="Email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Password">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
```

**http://jsfiddle.net/rwfje779/**